# Связующая таблица, добавление к ней сразу двух значений

Tags: php, массивы

```
    $sql = q("INSERT INTO book SET
            id_book = '',
            date_add = '".es(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))."',       
            title_book = '".es($_POST['title_book'])."',
            annot_book = '".es($_POST['annot_book'])."',
            descr_book = '".es($_POST['descr_book'])."'");
    $id_book= DB::_()->insert_id;
    $a_f_author = array();
    foreach($_POST['FIO_author'] as $key=>$value){
    $f = array(0=>'NULL',1=>'"'.$value.'"',2=>'"'.$_POST['alias'][$key].'"');
    $a_f_author[] = '(' . implode(',', $f) . ')';}
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO author_book (id_author,FIO,alias) VALUES" .implode(',', $a_f_author);
    echo wtf($sql2);
//Результат без запроса,просто вывод на экран:
INSERT INTO author_book (id_author,FIO,alias) VALUES(NULL,"Ибрагимов","Ибра"),(NULL,"Файзуллин","Фейз")
```

**Книга - Связующая таблица - Автор.**

1. Добавил автора к таблица Автор
2. Добавил книгу к таблице Книга.

Но не могу понять как добавить id двух авторов к Связующей таблице?..

Comment: а какие данные приходят в POST - как там задается соответствие авторов к книгам ?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант связки one-to-many, many-to-one плохо подходит для данной задачи.
Я бы рекомендовал вам использовать для связи книг и авторов many-to-many.
Т.е. три таблицы (авторы, книги и таблица связей (book_id, author_id)).
Таким образом у одной книги может быть несколько авторов, и у одного автора несколько книг.